# Cannot switch to amd proprietary driver

Tags: ati, 14.04, fglrx

I’m using ubuntu 14.04 on HP ProBook 4730s with AMD HD 6400m GPU.
I have some problems with proprietary\Opensource AMD driver in different games.
So i have to switch between drivers to play a particular game
I'm switching in System settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
But for some reason its not changing any more. It says "1 Proprietary driver in use"
But it uses opensource driver

I tried to fully uninstall & install fglrx driver - no effect.
`aticonfig --initial` says that no supported GPU found

lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

And AMD says that is supported
if I try to install latest driver from AMD site it fails with same error

```
your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver
```

How can I finally get it work?